# CollapsingToolbarLayout: position the ExpandedText programmatically

Tags: android

I am using the new Android support design view CollapsingToolbarLayout.
I have the need to position the ExpandedTitle programmatically.

Actually the only way to set a position for the ExpandedTitle is in the .xml file (example here: https://goo.gl/L5H5FC) but there is no public api to set the text position programmatically and the fields are all *private*.

Do you know if it's possible without reflection or any 'hacky' tricks?

Answer (score 2):

I have quickly solved my problem exposing the properties via *reflection* (https://gist.github.com/fpezzato/8e7d45112883dbbc5ffb), I works perfectly but I don't like to use this trick in production code.

*@Google: please no more private or final stuff! :)*

Comment: Thanks for the gist! Hopefully Google opens up these fields soon.